# C# Service not moving files to correct folder

Tags: c#, xml, service

I have configured a windows service using an xml config file. The service is supposed to determine which folder a csv file goes to depending on the number of fields in the file. The number of fields also determines which version of the software generated the file, whether Version 3 or Version 4. Version 3 csv files should go to its own folder and the same for version 4 before they are collated. Currently both versions are mixed up and because of this, the collation process gets corrupted and multiple files are not being processed by the windows service. Below is a sample of the code snippets. When I run the windows service and check the event viewer, I keep getting the error in the catch statement - "Error checking csv file" and It moves the files to the exception folder instead of to the correct folders. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**Config File**

```
<dip>
  <versions>
    <version number="4">
      <location path="C:\xRS\Output" />
      <numberOfFields>26</numberOfFields>
      <orderedfields>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>int</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>currency</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>currency</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>currency</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
      </orderedfields>
    </version>
    <version number="3">
      <location path="C:\xRS\Output" />
      <numberOfFields>23</numberOfFields>
      <orderedfields>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>currency</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>currency</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>currency</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
        <type>string</type>
      </orderedfields>
    </version>
  </versions>
</dip>
```

**Check CSV file for special character and check which version it was generated by**

```
private Boolean CheckCsvFile(String currentFile)
        {
            bool result = false;
            //bool proceed = false;
            int typeIndex;
            string currentLineValue;

            try
            {
                string[] line = File.ReadAllLines(currentFile);

                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    //remove all quotes
                    line[0] = Regex.Replace(line[0], "\"", String.Empty);

                    String[] lineValues = line[0].Split('\t');
                    //proceed = true;

                    eventLog1.WriteEntry("There are " + lineValues.Length + " columns in file");

                    XmlDocument dipConfig = new XmlDocument();
                    dipConfig.Load("DipConfig.xml");


                    foreach (XmlNode versions in dipConfig.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        // string nodename = versions.Name;
                        foreach (XmlNode versionNode in versions)
                        {
                            typeIndex = 0;

                            //  nodename = versionNode.Name;
                            string versionNumber = versionNode.Attributes["number"].InnerText;
                            string locationPath = versionNode.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["path"].InnerText;
                            string numberOfFields = versionNode.ChildNodes[1].InnerText;

                            eventLog1.WriteEntry(String.Format("Processing version {0} with {1} number of fields", versionNumber, numberOfFields));

                            //if the number of fields for the version matches the columns from the line
                            if (int.Parse(numberOfFields) == lineValues.Length)
                            {

                                //check each value
                                foreach (XmlNode typeNode in versionNode.ChildNodes[2])
                                {
                                    currentLineValue = lineValues[typeIndex];

                                    //if the line value is not empty checked the field type
                                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentLineValue))
                                    {
                                        if ("int".Equals(typeNode.InnerText.ToLower()))
                                        {
                                            int value;
                                            int.TryParse(currentLineValue, out value);
                                            lineValues[typeIndex] = value.ToString();
                                        }

                                        if ("currency".Equals(typeNode.InnerText.ToLower()))
                                        {
                                            lineValues[typeIndex] = Regex.Replace(currentLineValue, " ", String.Empty);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    typeIndex++; // increment the index
                                }

                                // write back the editted array to the current file
                                //construct the string

                                String EditedLine = String.Empty;
                                for (int i = 0; i < lineValues.Length; i++)
                                {
                                    EditedLine = @"\t" + lineValues[i];
                                }

                                try
                                {
                                    File.WriteAllText(currentFile, EditedLine);
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    eventLog1.WriteEntry("Error writing contents back to csv file");
                                }

                                result = true;
                                break; // break foreach loop
                            }

                        } //End For each version

                    } //End For Loop [versions]


                }
                return result;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry("Erroe while checking CSV file");
                return result;
            }
        }
```

Comment: So stop throwing away the exception and showing your own message, and see what the actual problem is that's causing the exception to be thrown. It's useless to have that information in the exception object and just discard it. You're discarding every single error and replacing that information with your own useless message that conveys no information.

Comment: What ken said... also you do know you can attach a debugger to a windows service and set break points

Comment: So replace my message with "throw"? or is there a different way to display the exception being caught? General, I have walked through the debugger and the data is being passed through as I wouldve expected it to, unless Im missing something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the additional exception message I was getting the ArgumentOutOfBounds Exception. I realized that I had 26 elements in my version 3 config section when I should've had 23. After deleting the last 3 elements Everything ran smoothly.